# renaming pandas df dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My df looks like below :-
[image]

I have to rename the columns and extract the numbers which I am doing with the below code:-

```
df.rename(columns={
                    0: 'latency_msecs.xmpp_login', 1: 'latency_msecs.total', 2: 'latency_msecs.message_send',
                    3: 'latency_msecs.admin_login', 4: 'latency_msecs.join_echo_channel',
                    5: 'latency_msecs.message_query',},
                    inplace=True)

df['latency_msecs.xmpp_login'] = df['latency_msecs.xmpp_login'].str.extract(r'(\d+.\d+)').astype('float')
df['latency_msecs.total'] = df['latency_msecs.total'].str.extract(r'(\d+.\d+)').astype('float')
df['latency_msecs.message_send'] = df['latency_msecs.message_send'].str.extract(r'(\d+.\d+)').astype('float')
df['latency_msecs.admin_login'] = df['latency_msecs.admin_login'].str.extract(r'(\d+.\d+)').astype('float')
df['latency_msecs.join_echo_channel'] = df['latency_msecs.join_echo_channel'].str.extract(r'(\d+.\d+)').astype('float')
df['latency_msecs.message_query'] = df['latency_msecs.message_query'].str.extract(r'(\d+.\d+)').astype('float')
```

Its giving me a clean df :-

[image]

How I can make the renaming and the extraction dynamic so that if my column value is `"latency_msecs.message_query": 68858.58869552612`, I can make the column name `latency_msecs.message_query` and the value will `be 68858.58869552612` doesn't matter if there are 5 rows or 500.

**I want to ditch the manual renaming and extraction.**

Comment: Please give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and also what if there are multiple rows, how it will be the output?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert json to pandas dataframe. Check the code below:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

sample_row = '{"latency_msecs.total": 71815.09041786194, "latency_msecs.message_query": 68858.58869552612, "latency_msecs.join_echo_channel": 10.111570358276367, "latency_msecs.message_send": 9.004592895507812, "latency_msecs.xmpp_login": 1941.108226776123, "latency_msecs.admin_login": 17.666339874267578}'

df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(sample_row))
print(df)
```

Comment: Seems  you have changed your question now. Please refer to earlier question. The json is just a specific format and can be written as string.

Comment: @AwadheshPathak's solution worked for me, and auto-converted each column to type float64.

Comment: even though I am struggling to fix AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize'

Comment: You may have to update the pandas version. You can check what version of pandas you have and in what version json.normalize is available.